# Seeking Advice: Javascript replacement of flash element -USA Map

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript

Here's a fictional example of what i'm trying to replace

http://ryanhollingsworth.com/test/map.html

Goal: input a series of state abbreviations and a hex value and have a dynamic map i can update quickly or use php to update on the fly.

I've been looking for a solution for a couple of weeks via google, figured i'd humble myself and ask. I don't want to reinvent the wheel and develop something that's already been done if i don't have to :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/new_map_charts should provide a quick and easy solution, although it is somewhat limited.

Comment: thanks, i've seen a google maps thing, but not this specific thing. this has potential.. it's just messy. (I can make this work, but am hoping for something a little cleaner) The copy/paste API code they provide doesn't seem to work, may be resolved since this is relatively new. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I used the Geochart API from google and I was able to create something very similar to your mockup image: http://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/usa-custom-election-map/

The API is very simple to use.